# Exporting project in Java(Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I wrote a simple game with 2D graphics in Java (Eclipse) and lib Slick2D. When I export project to Runnable Jar File in Eclipse and try to run this file just nothing happens. I can run this game in Eclipse without any problems. When I write `java` and put my jar in console to get path and hit enter i have sth like that:

> C:\Users\Me>java C:\Users\Jolanta\Desktop\pnd.jar Error: Could not
>   find or load main class C:\Users\Jolanta\Desktop\pnd.jar

In launch configuration while exporting I selected right main class. Any ideas?

Comment: when you right click on project and select export, next(don't click finish) until the last page, there you need to specify the class contains main method

Answer (score 0):

it's command for starting jar file with main class:
java -jar C:\Users\Jolanta\Desktop\pnd.jar

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide native libraries along with the jar file. Here are some scripts that will launch your game:

- windows (.bat file) :

  java -Djava.library.path="native/windows/" -jar pnd.jar
- linux :

  java -Djava.library.path="native/linux/" -jar pnd.jar

where your directory will look like this:

your .jar and scripts are in the same directory along with 'native' folder.
not sure where I got this folder from, I can send it to you if you want